# Mint color calibration is disabled

Tags: display, linux-mint

I just install Linux Mint Debian Edition in at laptop `Dell XPS M1530`. I want to calibrate the color of the screen but, when I open `Menu > Preferences > Color` dialog, the calibrate options is always disabled.

I also tried `dispcalGUI`, and also the calibrate buttons are disabled.

How can I do it?

**UPDATE:** I'm using Cinnamon

Comment: Are you using Mate or Cinnamon?

Comment: I'm using cinnamon

Comment: Which calibration device are you using?

Comment: What is a calibration device? is it a hardware device? I have nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to install package `gnome-color-manager` to enable this functionality:

```
sudo apt install gnome-color-manager
```

Comment: that doest have a calibrate button